# Laravel send email using MDaemon Email Server but getting error "authentication required"

Tags: php, laravel, email

I'm trying to send email with my laravel local app using [MDaemon WorldClient Private Email](http://www.altn.com/Worldclient-Private-Email/) email server but i always get this error

```
Expected response code 250 but got code "530", with message "530 5.7.0 Authentication required"
```

With my laravel local app, I already tried to send email using mailtrap and gmail and both works fine.

This is my email configuration in .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=mail.emaildomain.co.id
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=myname@emaildomain.co.id
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
```

To see if there's something wrong with my email configutraion, I also tried to send email using outlook on my computer with the same email account and configuration that I use on laravel and it works perfectly on outlook. I already double check the outlook SMTP configuration and the laravel but I have no idea why it always fails on laravel.

By the way, i'm using mailable on laravel.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry I did a silly mistake.

It's just the `from` parameter of the email and the email `username` doesn't match.

Just for a tip, make sure you set all the email config on the `.env` file. It'll help you a lot. I did the mistake because I set the `from` parameter in `Mailable` class and the other in `.env`.